# get last part of this URL

Tags: jquery, regex, url

I am grabbing this strange URL out of an Object in a Twitter button:

http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1329950604.html#_=1330013339435&count=none&hashtags=allstar&id=twitter-widget-10&lang=en&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fpulse%2Fallstar%2F2012%2Findex.html&related=%40nba&size=m&text=Sprite%20Slam%20Dunk%20Contest%20is%20trending%20on%20NBA%20All-Star%20Pulse%20&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fpulse%2Fallstar%2F2012%2Ftopics%2Fspriteslamdunk.html

I need to get the last part before the '.html' which in the example above is:spriteslamdunk

this seems to appear after %2Ftopics%2F

not sure how to extract that with jQuery?

[EDIT]  Looks like I have to do it with Regex?  Haven't done much with Regex in this regard??

Comment: You want to do basic string manipulation … why would you involve jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var answer = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("%2F") + 3).replace(".html","")

Answer (score 3):

I guess you might have to use regex `"(\w+)\.html$"`

Comment: (\w+) includes the 2F part right before the part he wants to keep (2Fspriteslamdunk).

Comment: @DaveS I agree. If this will always be the case, he can always just `substring(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve the string before `.html` and after the last appearance of `%2F`.

You could use the regular expression `/%2F([^%]+?)(\.html$)/`. `\.html$` matches the string before last appearance; `([^%]+?)` part matches the shortest string which doesn't include `%` and before `.html` which is what you want to retrieve; `%2F` excludes this string in matches.

```
var str = "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1329950604.html#_=1330013339435&count=none&hashtags=allstar&id=twitter-widget-10&lang=en&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fpulse%2Fallstar%2F2012%2Findex.html&related=%40nba&size=m&text=Sprite%20Slam%20Dunk%20Contest%20is%20trending%20on%20NBA%20All-Star%20Pulse%20&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fpulse%2Fallstar%2F2012%2Ftopics%2Fspriteslamdunk.html"

var matches = str.match(/%2F([^%]+?)(\.html$)/)

matches
// => ["%2Fspriteslamdunk.html", "spriteslamdunk", ".html"]

matches[1] // What you want.
```